# how do I change checkbox value if checkbox is checked in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to change the value when the checkbox is checked.

My HTML:

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="textMessage" id="tm" value="0" /><span class="text">Unlimited text messages $5 / month</span>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
if(document.getElementById('tm').checked){
        document.getElementById('tm').value = 5;
    }else

    if(document.getElementById('tm').checked){
        document.getElementById('tm').value = 0;
    }
```

My value is still 0 when my checkbox is checked, what's wrong with my JavaScript?

Comment: Have you been banned from Google?

Comment: This questions demonstrates a lack of research. There's already plenty of examples on how to do this elsewhere.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service, it is a Question and Answer site. Please review [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="textMessage" id="tm" value="0" 
onclick=this.value=5;alert(this.value)/><span class="text">Unlimited text messages $5 / 
month</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tgajD/).

If you inspect the element in dev tools, you will see that the value attribute has changed to 5.  If you want to change what the text actually says, that will be a little bit different, but let me know if that's what you need.

```
$(".checkbox").on("change", function () {
    $(this).attr("value", 5);
});
```